# В каких случаях разумно заменять метку [дефект] на [поддержка]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, мета

Хорошо известно, что механики сайтов Stack Exchange довольно разнообразны. Новым участникам может потребоваться потратить существенное количество времени, чтобы разобраться что и как здесь работает. Из-за этого могут возникать довольно любопытные ситуации. Например, участник считает некоторое поведение ошибкой и задаёт вопрос с соответствующей мета-меткой [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82). Но на самом деле оказывается, что предполагаемое ошибочное поведение является вполне себе осмысленным, если знать о некоторых нюансах сайта. И здесь рождается новый вопрос.

В первую очередь, конечно, имеет смысл опубликовать ответ, поясняющий ситуацию о том, что дефект вовсе не является дефектом. А вот дальше дилемма:

- Ждать/позвать модератора, чтобы он поставил красную метку [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be)
- Заменить самостоятельно метку [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) на [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Оба варианта кажутся достойными существования, но при этом они, конечно, не эквиваленты. Как вы считаете, в каких случаях стоит выбирать тот или иной вариант? Или может быть есть ещё что-то другое? А может разница совсем не важна, раз уж суть вопроса раскрыта автору и ответ получен, то какая разница какие будут метки?

Comment: Я думаю, что метка [дефект] должна сопровождаться меткой [поддержка] — т.е. [дефект] предполагает, что его будут фиксить т.е. предполагает [поддержку]. А [поддержка] — это метка более широкого смысла. Например для вопросов связанных с модерацией тоже стоит использовать эту метку (обычно).

Comment: @VictorVosMottor [поддержка] это о другом. Почитайте описание меток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как модераторов всегда меньше, чем обычных, но активных участников, то наиболее предпочтительным вариантом будет именно замена метки [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) на [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0). Это может сделать любой и не нужно ждать/звать модератора, который неизвестно когда сможет появиться на соответствующей странице вопроса. С точки зрения разрешения ситуации этот подход даёт тот же эффект. Главное, чтобы ответ был получен.